# Write ASCII command with Pyserial

Tags: python, ascii, pyserial

I am using a kunbus RevPi connect + to control a pump with a USB serial converter. To control it, I need to send ASCII command so I try to use the Pyserial library.

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB2', baudrate = 9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=1)

print (ser.portstr)

ser.write(b"1H[CR]")
```

I haven't error message but the pump doesn' start.

Can you help me please?

Comment: I assume that `[CR]` came from the pump's documentation?  That almost certainly means a carriage return character, which would be written `\r` in a Python string literal.

Comment: Exactly about the [CR]! I try your sugestion but it doesn't work..

Comment: Do you have an other idea?